# Magento multistore/multiview default page

Tags: php, magento, web

I have 1 website with multiple store / views. What I want to accomplish is to have on the main domain page which will give me to choose between languages. So far i created the page and on default configuration web for default web url im putting the choose your language page. For store view default page is language and cms home page is the different.
How i can accomplish when user comes to the domain.com to choose language and after that to be redirected to the site.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your apache configuration.

Setup the stores in the admin panel and use their store code as the MAGE_RUN_CODE you need to set.

```
www.domainnameone.com -> MAGE_RUN_CODE = 'english'
www.domainnametwo.com -> MAGE_RUN_CODE = 'french'

ServerAlias domainnameone.com
SetEnvIf HOST domainnameone.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=english
```

Comment: Hello thank you for response @Vladimir Ramik. My stores are as follows domain.com/?___store=es, domain.com/?___store=fr,domain.com/?___store=de. So how can implement this using .htaccess or index.php since i have in index.php directive $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve this.
First I created CMS page for all store views with language flags and named start.html.
After that I created new store named choose your language with store view named chose.
In system/configuration/web for Default Web URL i put domain.com and for default page set start page
In store scope for english for Default Web URL i put cms and for default page Home
In store scope for 2nd language Default Web URL i put cms default page Franch home page 
In store scope for choose your language store for default i set domain.com/start.html and for default page start.

I hope it will help for others maybe it is not clean solution but it does the job.